# connecting to web service with classic asp

Tags: json, web-services, asp-classic

i was given a project to write JSON from Classic ASP and upload the info to a web service given by a third party.

Third Party:

Connecting to the web service:
The web service works over the HTTP protocol. It is recommended that this web service, once in production, use a Secure Socket Layer (HTTPS). The web service is designed to work with the URL: http://domainname.com/api/push

The site uses an authentication token in the header to prevent crawlers from interfering with the web service. When sending data add a header called HTTP_TOKENKEY with the value of ABCDEFGHIJK. This is one reason why HTTPS is recommended.
The web service will look for JSON data in the request’s POST and sends JSON responses back to the client.

I was able to produce the JSON without a sweat, but cannot connect to their web service via classic ASP.  I MUST USE classic asp :(

please help... thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest to send a SOAP message via Classic ASP. I did this some years back (2004 I think). Here is an article that shows how to do it:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/ASP/An-Introduction-To-XML-SOAP-Using-ASP-and-VB6/

Pete

Comment: is there a way to do without touching the server? i just want to upload the JSON Data to that api because i do not have access to the server side to register any dll. 

Thank you!!

Comment: Yes I think you can do this using JavaScript: var o = new ActiveXObject("MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest");